# What happens in this operation?

Tags: r, calculation

I'm studying R in a Google program and I'm having difficulties with operations. I wrote the same code than the "teacher" but RStudio dont give me the result, just show: Error: unexpected input in "midyear_sales ˂"

Our first calculation

```
quarter_1_sales ˂- 35657.98

quarter_2_sales ˂- 43810.55

midyear_sales ˂- quarter_1_sales + quarter_2_sales


Error: unexpected input in "midyear_sales ˂"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your text the less-than sign is represented as:

`"˂" (U+02C2 MODIFIER LETTER LEFT ARROWHEAD)`.

but it should be represented as:

`"<" (U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN).`

So, the primary difference is in the representation of the less-than sign. The first uses a Unicode character that looks similar but is a distinct character, while the second line uses the standard less-than sign.

The correct less than or equal symbol, is on most qwerty keyboards, to the right of the `M` key, and the wrong one that you gave an example of wouldnt be directly keyable needing one to use charmap or type in a sequence of codes to bring out; or perhaps this was copy pasted from some odd source.